# Jquery Revealed nav doesn't hide when clicking 'Home'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, navigation

I have a site that has a sort of intro navigation on the home page. When selecting an option, a nav bar appears. I need it to hide again when I click on "Home". The first section of code works properly. It's the second half I'm having trouble with:

```
//Show navbar on page scroll
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  $("nav").fadeIn(1400);
  var navSeen = true;
});

//Hide navbar if #home is clicked
$("#home").click(function(){
   $("nav").fadeOut(1400);
   var navSeen = false;
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT -- All JS in the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
////////////////////////////////
//Lock Dog in place when scrolling right
var dogLock = $('#dog').position().left;
$(window).scroll(function() {
if(dogLock >= $(window).scrollLeft()) {
    if($('#dog').hasClass('leftLock')) {
        $('#dog').removeClass('leftLock');
    }
} else { 
    if(!$('#dog').hasClass('leftLock')) {
        $('#dog').addClass('leftLock');
    }
}
});
//If the connect tab is open and you click outside, then exit out of it!
var menu_state_ = true;
$('#connect').click( function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
if (menu_state_up){
    menu_state_Down();
} else {
menu_state_Up();
}

return false;
});
$('html').click(function() {
menu_state_Up();
});


function menu_state_Down() {
$("#connect-window").fadeIn(200);
menu_state_up = false;
}
function menu_state_Up() {
$("#connect-window").fadeOut(200);
menu_state_up =true;
}
//Ease into each transition
$(function() { 
$('.link').bind('click',function(event){
var $anchor = $(this);
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left - 300
 },600,'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
//Big Text Plugin
$('.intro').bigtext();

//If the page has scrolled then display the hidden menu
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  $("nav").fadeIn(1400);
  var navSeen = true;
});

//Hide navbar if #home is clicked
$("#home").click(function() {
   $("nav").fadeOut(1400);
   var navSeen = false;
});

//////////////////////////////////////////
});
</script>
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/pQ3by/.

Comment: I added the additional JS for clarification.

Comment: what happens if you click on it? nothing or produce an error?  if you put it inside a .ready() function, does it work then?

Comment: Nothing happens. JavaScript console shows no errors, and the menu doesn't hide. It is within a .ready() function already, and trying an additional, didn't fix it either.

Comment: the code you added above is wrapped with script tags, but it's in a JS file?  If so, remove <script type="text/javascript"> 
and </script> from the js file :)

Comment: Sorry, it's a php file. That's the JS in the file.

Comment: I found that if I click on home, and then click elsewhere on the page (html), it disappears.

Comment: use the browsers DEV tools (F12 in chrome and IE), and in the scripting tab, put a line break on the line with $("nav").fadeIn(1400);   Then see what value you get for this: 
$("#home")
If it's null, that's yoru problem - it's not rendered yet.  If it's there, sometimes moving your script from the top of the page to the bottom of the page (right before </body>) can fix it.  I've had a lot of problems with JS functions not being in the right part of the page lately  >.<  Hope this helps

Comment: a sample page of what you're using would help :)  not sure how the other posters were able to trully test it with Fiddle using just the code you posted above - i can confirm there are no errors, but that's about it :)

Comment: Maybe $('#home') does not exist, in which case you need to 1/ define it into a document.ready-based function, or 2/ use live() instead of click(), or 3/ use delegate() instead of the previous. Also, you variable navSeen declared in both your anonymous functions is totally useless: it is declared as a local variable, therefore does not exist anywhere but inside the function, and it is not of any use inside that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by binding the hide to the clicking of home (the only page on which the menu is hidden), and not the scrolling of the page. Thanks for the help folks!